Is William Dembski’s argument for Intelligent Design self undermining?
William Dembski, a proponent of the ID movement, uses the concept of specified complexity to argue for design.
As the SEP article on Creationism states (relevant part bolded at the end):

The example that Dembski uses is the message from outer space received in the movie Contact. The series of dots and dashes, zeros and ones, could not be deduced from the laws of physics. But do they show evidence of design? Suppose we can interpret the series in a binary fashion, and the initial yield is the number group, 2, 3, 5. As it happens, these are the beginning of the prime-number series, but with so small a yield no one is going to get very excited. It could just be chance. So no one is going to insist on design yet. But suppose now you keep going on the series, and it turns out that it yields in exact and precise order the prime numbers up to 101. Now you will start to think that something is up, because the situation seems just too complex to be mere chance. It is highly improbable. ‘Complexity as I am describing it here is a form of probability….’ (Dembski 2000, 27).


But although you are probably happy now to conclude (on the basis of the prime-number sequence) that there are extraterrestrials out there, in fact there is another thing needed. ‘If I flip a coin 1000 times, I will participate in a highly complex (that is, highly improbable) event…. This sequence of coin tosses will not, however, trigger a design inference. Though complex, this sequence will not exhibit a suitable pattern.’ Here, we have a contrast with the prime-number sequence from 2 to 101. ‘Not only is this sequence complex, but it also embodies a suitable pattern. The SETI researcher who in the movie Contact discovered this sequence put it this way: “This isn’t noise, this has structure”’ (pp. 27–8). What is going on here? You recognize in design something which is not just arbitrary or chance or which is given status only after the experiment or discovery, but rather something that was or could be in some way specified, insisted upon, before you set out. You know or could work out the sequence of prime numbers at any time before or after the contact from space. The random sequence of penny tosses will come only after the event. ‘The key concept is that of “independence”. I define a specification as a match between an event and an independently given pattern. Events that are both highly complex and specified (that is, that match an independently given pattern) indicate design.’

But would this not apply to God Himself and thus indicate that He must also be designed?
God can be specified in the sense of His particular attributes (omnipotence/omnisicence/etc). And clearly, out of all the ways a Being could have been, or all the ways reality could have been structured, only one of them would include the existence of this very specific God.
Is this argument then self undermining with respect to God in that it would not lead to the conclusion that Dembski envisions? Dembski, needless to say, concludes that God must exist
From Google, (AI summary),

…he concludes that the complex and specified information found in the universe, particularly in biological systems, points towards the existence of a designer, which he identifies as God

I presume that the retort to this would be that the concept of specified complexity wouldn’t apply to God since He consists of no parts or some other reason a theist can think of, but I’m not sure how this wouldn’t be committing the special pleading fallacy. If the theist does this, then I’m also not sure why a person can’t come up with reasons as to why a particular natural pattern doesn’t fit the concept of specified complexity.
EDIT: apparently some commenters wanted a source for the conclusion that Dembski believes in god (even though it’s widely known that he’s a proponent of ID), but see this video here where he goes through the argument for specified complexity: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2qyGQyUkqMQ

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

To understand this, just apply Bayes' formula.
P(design | observation) = P(observation | design) P(design) / P(observation)
For an observation to make design more likely, the factor P(observation | design) / P(observation) must be large, which is to say that the observation must be more likely under the assumption of design, as compared to the prior assumptions. It is not enough for the observation to simply be unlikely by itself; the ratio is what matters.
Dembski's notion of "specified complexity" is crude approximation of this. To quote it again:

Events that are both highly complex and specified (that is, that match an independently given pattern) indicate design.

This isn't exactly right. It is not enough to match just any independently given pattern. Newton's law of gravitation is an independently given pattern, but we do not suggest that the fact falling objects follow this law proves they were designed. No, the events must match a pattern that is more likely under the assumption of design than under the prior assumptions.
Also, this phrase "indicate design" is rather slippery. Such events make design more likely than before we observed them - but this does not mean design is likely overall ("indicated"), because the prior probability of design (P(design) in the formula) may have been very low. God is typically envisioned as a being with humanlike attributes, which indicates it is very complex, and therefore has a very low prior probability.

So am I understanding: if God works out as an answer to the question, then God is not very likely?

@ScottRowe Probably more accurate to say that if "existence of God" is a hypothesis you want to test, and God as proposed by all major religions is much more intelligent than we are, then observations suggest that the quality of "design" makes it improbable God designed it. (Consider the existence of human doctors who deeply understand the inherent defects of bodies; if the design hypothesis was true, the designer would be likely to be less intelligent than a doctor who has to fix that design.)

What is your argument for complexity implying improbability? I understand that this is intuitive but I’m wondering whether there are any formal justifications for this

@Syed There are several ways to argue for that. One way is to note that "A and B" must always be less likely than "A" and also less likely than "B," and if A and B are independent then P(A and B) = P(A) P(B). So a hypothesis made from the conjunction of many independent elements is exponentially less likely as the number of elements increases. Another way is to note that if you have a countable infinity of hypotheses, there is some length L such that the probability you assigned to hypotheses shorter than L is at least 0.99999... (from the definition of a limit)

Another way is to note that for a language to be an efficient means of transmitting information, it must use shorter strings to communicate higher-probability ideas (a la Shannon's source coding theorem). So if we assume English (for example) is relatively efficient at transmitting ideas, then more likely ideas would be communicated with more concise English sentences.

@causative for the limits argument, is this equivalent to saying that one cannot construct a probability distribution over an infinite number of hypotheses without making the shorter ones more likely? Can’t one just do the opposite? Make more complex hypotheses more and more likely? Or no because then the probabilities won’t add up to 1? I believe we discussed this earlier but I did just post a question about modeling hypotheses as turing machines if you want to take a look

God is a very precisely specified being indeed. I like to say "We are so lucky to be in a universe with such a loving, human-friendly God!"
I say this to highlight your same concern -- the God we posit seems so self-servingly tuned to human needs and concerns. Attempts to get around this may be successful in a strictly logical sense but from an evidential and "noncommitted observer" viewpoint, they seem contrived and akin to excuses vs explanations.
Simple question: If the world were such that no evil occurred, good things happened to good people, and we were always happy, would Theists be nervous that God doesn't exist since God is supposed to generate a world exactly like ours? I don't think so. They'll take every scrap of confirmation they can muster. The "sophisticated views" are merely to give intellectual credence to the fact that God isn't as glaringly obvious as he should be a priori.

I'm wondering how God feels about the hundreds of billions of stars in each of the hundreds of billions of other galaxies? Is He just "especially fond of" Earth?

@ScottRowe - good question, especially the stars and things outside our "Hubble bubble" - we'll never, ever see those and they cannot have any impact on us.

Good point. Still, the bubble is really, really big.


But would this not apply to God Himself and thus indicate that He must also be designed?

No, Dembskis argument is restricted to historical events with an observed change between before and after. Dembski is talking about observed DNA mutations specifically, but would apply the same to other events in history.
For the gods that seem relevant here, there is no observation or revelation about some event with a before without god and some after with a god that would allow checking if that event was by design or not. For other deities like in the greek pantheon, there is insufficient theological foundation to argue about whether those were created/designed or not.
The reduced argument "If anything complex was designed, and god is complex, god must also be designed" is not a fair representation of Dembskis argument in the cited SEP article.
ID is a pseudoscience and not philosophy for many reasons, but this fallacious argument of being able to discern natural from designed events based on specification is fallacious and garbage for other reasons. It is no threat to faith even if it were not garbage.

He deduces intelligent design from specified complexity. As long as something is complex (improbable) and specified (can be summarized), then it has specified complexity. You are merely restating the fallacy of begging the question. You can’t just say “here is the concept of specified complexity. Oh btw, it can’t apply to an intelligent designer” and then argue for intelligent design based on it.

That's not what I said, and "specified = can be summarized" is not what Demski wrote. You are burning strawmen.
If you don't want answers because you think only you know the true answer, your question should also be closed as pushing a personal philosophy (as if there were not enough reasons to close that question yet).

Short Answer
Well, yeah, it undermines itself. If you’re sayin complex things need a designer, then God—who is super-specific and complex would also need a designer. Unless you make an exception for God, which is just special pleading
Long Answer
Dembski’s "specified complexity" argument says that if something is super complex and matches a specific pattern, it must have been designed. Fine, let’s play along. But if you apply this same logic to God, it backfires. God is incredibly specific (omnipotent, omniscient, eternal, etc.), and out of all possible realities the one where this exact God exists would seem pretty "improbable." So by Dembski’s rules, God would also need a designer.
Now... A common response is, "God is different—He’s simple, not made of parts, or eternal." But this feels like making up a rule just to protect God. That’s called special pleading—setting up a rule for everything except the one thing you want to exempt.
The bigger issue here is that this whole argument isn’t really about finding the truth. It’s about starting with "God exists" and working backward to justify it. Science doesn’t work like that. It looks for explanations based on evidence, not exceptions. For example, the SETI example (prime numbers in a signal) works because we know natural processes don’t generate patterns like that, but intelligent beings might. But saying "God explains everything" is just replacing one mystery (the universe) with an even bigger one (God)

"If you’re sayin complex things need a designer"  that is not what the specified complexity argument says.  See:  https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/99479/29339


Materialism demands a deep ignorance of reality, and it deserves to be judged as a kind of intellectual darkness.
The fact is that the world is plainly more than atoms in the void and
man is plainly more than an evolved meat machine. Our beliefs and
judgments and insight — all that make us human — are immaterial, and
it is obvious that transcendent purpose permeates nature. To
understand ourselves and the true nature of existence, we must study
theology, philosophy, logic, ethics, metaphysics, literature, fine
arts, history, medicine, mathematics, anthropology, sociology, natural
science, and psychology, just to start with. Biology and physics and
chemistry are important, no doubt, but man and nature transcend
physical science and cannot be reduced to it.
https://evolutionnews.org/2014/12/materialism_oug/

I am trying to understand from which research background a large portion of this community who are pushing consistent physicalism are coming from. This flat and simplified view of our reality is inconsistent with the majority of philosophical studies.

I think it is a starting point. Unless we find something to agree on, there won't be much point in debate. What do you think?

It is hard to debate in the face of absolute confidence. It is similar to having a political argument with Trump supporters.

Re : "... inconsistent with the majority of philosophical studies." Then, worse for the majority of philosophical studies.

-1 for statements of faith without evidence, or even being grounded in philosophical studies. I mean, sure, if you limit your selection of philosophers to Western Europe circa 1000-1700, but that's self-selecting on "what won't I get executed for publishing".

@Graham - It is quite ridiculous to assume that if a person doesn't agree with consistent materialism, then this person automatically accepts bearded guy sitting on a cloud.

Maybe people shouldn't have absolute confidence?

@TheMatrixEquation-balance It certainly is.  It's more ridiculous to make false claims you wish were true though.  This is not consistent with the majority of philosophical studies - at best, these studies can only consider the possibility of it and attempt to consider the ramifications if this were the case.  It is not a fact, because there is no such evidence - and many philosophers consider that no such evidence could ever even exist.  It certainly is not "plain", for both those reasons.

@Graham - "It is not a fact, because there is no such evidence" - You are sitting in 700g of gray matter. This is the only fact there is for your great confidence in what you are saying.

...is inconsistent with the majority of philosophical studies Needs elaboration. The fact of the matter is that as I elaborated here »philosophy« invariably defaults to western Christian philosophy (before 1900) and western anti-Christian philosophy after 1900. If you are intentionally casting your net wider you need to say where and how

@Rushi - I am complaining about lunacyfication of the population. With clever and intelligent argument, I could understand and agree with both sides of the dispute (theism-atheism, forTrump-againstTrump).
